# Vim: Change bold font weight

Tags: vim, fonts, macvim, fira-code

Started using a new font in MacVim (FiraCode, paradox theme). This theme highlights some words in bold i.e. gui=bold in the theme file. This worked well with the previous font I was using, I like the bolding, but the highlighting with bold weight with this particular font is *too bold* IMO.

**Is there any way to tell Vim/MacVim to use a particular weight of font for bold *highlighting* e.g. 500 instead of 700?**

[image: Syntax highlighting code with bold being too bold]

I have resorted to simply disabling the bold font variant in my system fonts, now Vim seems to just ignore bold, but this doesn't seem like a great solution.

[image: Syntax highlighting code with bold font disabled in system]

Comment: FiraCode comes in several weights. If "bold" is too bold, did you consider trying "semi bold" or "medium"?

Comment: @romainl I would if I could figure out how to tell vim to use a different weight, that's the problem! :D

Comment: How is that a problem? You only have to `:set guifont=<the name of the font>` just like you do for bold and normal.

Comment: My guifont is set to the regular font. Normal text renders fine, but the theme is setting keywords to be highlighted with `bold`. I like this, it worked well with the previous font I was using but when using FiraCode, the bold is too bold. The problem is I don't see how to control which font/weight it uses for the ones highlighted with bold.

Comment: You can't do that.